# Search log file for entry range between 2 epoch times

Tags: perl, awk, epoch

I'm using `awk` to search a log file for a list of lines that fell between two epoch times.
This is what I've done... (I'm getting a massive list of entries)

```
awk '/([1480360000..1480380000])/' /Location/Data.txt
```

I'm also wanting to be able to replace the times with Perl Variables without having to use `[0-9][0-9]`and use it within a `perl` script. I'm puzzled.

```
system(awk '/([$MinRange..$MaxRange])/' /Location/Data.txt)
```

Thanks

Comment: You are misunderstanding the use of brackets in regular expressions. It needs to be more like `awk '$1 >= 1480360000 && $1 <= 1480380000' file`. Just change `1` to the correct field number.

Comment: You are spot on. I have a better understanding now. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to give an answer based on ooags comment.

To search from a number to a number:

```
cat file
1 one
2 two
3 thee
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
10 ten
```

```
awk '$1>=4 && $1<=8' file
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
```

Bracket are used to get from to within single letter or single number.
`[a-z]` from `a` to `z`
`[5-8]` from `5` to `8`
`[0-9][0-9][0-9]` from `000` to `999`
`([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])` this would give from `0` to `999`
etc

Comment: Perhaps `[0-9]{3}` and `[0-9]{1,3}` for the last 2 suggested regexes?  Or does introducing a new regex concept break the flow of your lesson?

Comment: @Miller For most `gnu awk` you then need to add the `--re-interval` to use this option. `[0-9]{1,3}` would give number like `08` and `003` instead of `8` and `3`.  This may or may not be ok, depends of the input data.

Comment: Yes, true, the second regex I suggested wouldn't restrict the case of 0 prefixes.  But your original regex wasn't bounded either, so could easily allow `00009` as a matched value.  I suppose that we could expand it to `\b(?:(?=0\b)|(?!0))[0-9]{1,3}\b`, but then we've definitely gotten off track from your original lesson.  :)

Comment: @Miller You are correct. Boundary is important when using regex.